# How to change the size of 3-dots overflow button in Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have changed the icon of default android 3-dots overflow button. But it is looking "stretched". How can i change its size to fixed values?
This is how it is looking now
[image]

And this is how i changed the icon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="MaterialActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
  <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MaterialOverFlow</item>

</style>

<style name="MaterialOverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/icon_overflow</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/material_overflow_button_background</item>

</style>
```

Got it! Finally converted my button from svg to xml and set fixed size for for it and now everything is looking nice)

Comment: if u use 24dp icons it will be correct

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And may be there are some alternate ways how to set the size of the icon in code or xml? Or this is the only way and we cannot modify system icons size?

Comment: use vector drawable for this

Comment: Thanks. Will try to convert it to xml

Comment: IntelliJ Shivam, thanks again converted my button from svg to vector drawable and got exactly what i needed!